# Android compound button through xml file

Tags: android, button, android-button

I am trying to use android's built in control `CompoundButton`, however I have no luck using it in xml, here is my code

```
<CompoundButton
    android:id="@+id/mini_recorder_play"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/play_d" />
```

it is throwing exception while inflating.

Comment: it seems like compoundbutton is abstract so it will not work .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CompoundButton` is an abstract class, you cannot instantiate it directly.  You must either instantiate one of its subclasses (e.g. `CheckBox`, `RadioButton`, `ToggleButton`) or create your own customized subclass if none of those widgets fits your needs.

HTH